# Irrational fear of reincarnation. Please help

Tags: consciousness, death

I’ve been having these irrational thoughts regarding reincarnation. I’m worried that after death, I will be reborn as a prey animal, farm animal or a new human with a shitty existence. I would have no memory of myself basically.

Because we where born once, why couldn’t happen it again? Why can’t I experience life as a new being. With a different mind, different personality, different body. It wouldn’t be the “me” now, it would be a new “me”. Anyways, do you guys fear this?

Could you explain why this may be unlikely.

Thanks

Comment: If your "new self" will have no memory of the previous one, why worry?

Comment: My new self could experience life as a new animal with a shittier existence, or a new human etc. It’s scary

Comment: Neither you nor your future self will know. Since there is no detrimental experience for you or the knowledge of a better existence for a possible future self, there is nothing to be afraid of. Which shows the crux of all of this: If all this holds, this "future self" will on no meaningful sense be **you**.

Comment: So, act with concern toward all the beings you could become. "No man is an Iland, intire of itselfe; every man
is a peece of the Continent, a part of the maine;
if a Clod bee washed away by the Sea, Europe
is the lesse, as well as if a Promontorie were, as
well as if a Manor of thy friends or of thine
owne were; any mans death diminishes me,
because I am involved in Mankinde;
And therefore never send to know for whom
the bell tolls; It tolls for thee." - John Donne

Answer (score 0):

Here the psycho doctor speaking. Don't be afraid. I know exactly what you mean. See it like this (it's how I deal with this fear):

Consider yourself a physical process (this doesn't mean you take away whatever feelings or experiences you have, nor that it devaluates them). You were born out of the huge chaotic but ordered sea of particles that existed since it originated at the big bang, long before you were born. You have the history of the universe inside of you. The particles that made you up during your life will never flow again like they did in you nor will they ever make up another animal (maybe some of your particles will be part of others like the air you breathe out can become part of people or animals around you).

So there is nothing to fear in this universe. All particles in our universe will eventually become separate or will be turned in photons.

There could be a new big bang though. After all particles have been accelerated away from each other a new big bang can appear behind them. So the particles that made you up here can reappear in the new universe after the new big bang. But how can you be sure that the new you isn't gonna be a red ant or a an animal with a shitty existence? You can't. But it is reasonable to assume it will be you again. Or maybe it will be black forever but this is even harder to imagine. Either dead or alive. When dead there is no experience so somehow there must be an afterlife. You don't experience time when dèad so it can take an eternity but it seems as if you are born again the moment you die. Dead or alive, one of the two. This means logically that someday you must live again.

So the best way of looking at it is to think you will be born again like yourself. For some people this might seem fearfull too. Maybe they are not satisfied with life or with themsekves. But things can always turn out better. The circumstances might be different (and worse, that is true). People who are not satisfied with themselves can always think they will be a beuatifull animal after death. Uptill death it is best to think about life in the here and now.

Answer (score 0):

So effectively what you're saying is that after your being dies, some other being will be born which isn't you (in body or mind), but has some transcendental thread that connects it to your being. You're worried that this *new* being will find itself in unpleasant circumstances, which somehow reflects on your (then deceased) being.

In that case, it's all really about that transcendental thread. That thread wants or needs to experience that new life, just as it wanted or needed to experience your life, and will want or need to experience a different life after the next being dies. What you imagine as an unpleasant context, it might see as a moment for growth, or an interesting challenge.

From the buddhist perspective there are things that you can do to influence that: i.e., teach your being to quell cravings and urges that lead to unfortunate outcomes, so that you don't project them forward. But all in all, if you keep in mind that the way things seem from the exceedingly limited perspective of a single being are not at all how things would seem from the perspective of a transcendental thread, you'll realize that there's nothing to worry about here.

Comment: No. I’m saying that there would be no connection to the “me” now. It would be a new “me”

Comment: It might be a 'new' you, but it wouldn't be 'you'. So if there's no connection between current 'you' and new 'you', how is this different from saying "After I die, some being will be born in some place and have an unpleasant life." You are creating a sense of identity between this being and that being, on completely arbitrary grounds, and worrying about it for unspecified reasons. Say that the very moment you die a chipmunk is born. Either there's a transcendental thread of identity between it and you or there isn't; and if there isn't, where is your problem?

Comment: Aren't we all connected, by such threads?